# How to use non-blocking connection function in libpq and trigger a notification or callback when the connection is established withlibpq — C Library?

Tags: c, postgresql, sockets

I am trying to establish a non-blocking connection to a PostgreSQL database using the libpq library in C, and I want to be able to trigger a notification or callback function once the connection is established.

I know that PQconnectStart() can be used to initiate a non-blocking connection and that PQconnectPoll() can be used to check the status of the connection, but I'm not sure how to trigger a notification or callback function once the connection is established.

```
PGconn *conn;
PGconnStatusType status;

conn = PQconnectStart("dbname=mydatabase user=myusername password=mypassword");

if (conn == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Connection initialization failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

while ((status = PQconnectPoll(conn)) != CONNECTION_OK) {
    if (status == PGRES_POLLING_FAILED) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection failed: %s\n", PQerrorMessage(conn));
        PQfinish(conn);
        exit(1);
    }
}

// Connection is established, how do I trigger a notification or callback function?

// Do something with the connection here...

PQfinish(conn);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. You'll have to call `select()` on the socket to poll if there is a response. You can start a thread or parallel process that polls with `select()`, the calls your callback.

Comment: i think you are right the only possible thing is to keep select() where I can create a thread, what I have done so far I created a while loop when the connection is really needed then once the connection is established I break the loop and fire a thread

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the **Notice Receiver**.

You can use **PQsetNoticeReceiver** to set a custom notice receiver callback function that will be called whenever a notice or warning message is received. This callback function can be used to handle and process the received messages according to your application's requirements.

[Documentation Notice Processing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-notice-processing.html)

Comment: That has nothing to do with non-blocking connect to the database.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Mind explaining why this is the case? Might help the mods clean up the many redundant answers on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after the connection is established, triggering a notification will make use of the `PQsetNoticeReceiver` function. It allows you to set a callback function that will be called whenever a warning message is received from PostgreSQL.

The trigger should be like so:

```
PQsetNoticeReceiver(conn, notificationHandler, NULL);
```

Where `notificationHandler` is the defined callback function.

Answer (score 0):

- You need to set a callback function for processing server notices using `PQsetNoticeProcessor`.
- `PQsetNoticeProcessor` should be called after `PQconnectStart` but before the connection is entirely established.
- For each notification or warning message received from the PostgreSQL server, your callback function will be called.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libpq-fe.h>

void noticeProcessor(void *arg, const char *message) {
    // Your callback function implementation
    printf("Notice from server: %s\n", message);
}

int main() {
    PGconn *conn;
    PGconnStatusType status;

    conn = PQconnectStart("dbname=mydatabase user=myusername password=mypassword");

    if (conn == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection initialization failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    PQsetNoticeProcessor(conn, noticeProcessor, NULL);

    while ((status = PQconnectPoll(conn)) != CONNECTION_OK) {
        if (status == PGRES_POLLING_FAILED) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Connection failed: %s\n", PQerrorMessage(conn));
            PQfinish(conn);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // Connection is established, noticeProcessor will handle server notices.


    PQfinish(conn);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This answer adds nothing to existing answers. Also weird that you'd mix `exit` and `return` like that. Do you really understand the code here?